# Windows - Wait on event and socket simulatenously

Tags: c, windows, sockets, winapi, ipc

I'm writing Win32-API C code that needs to wait for new TCP connections and on the other side can be closed at any time by any other process/thread.

Therefore, I need to somehow WaitForSingleObject on the stop event and wait for connections using WSAAccept simultaneously.

I tried WaitForMultipleObjects on both socket and handle but new connection won't trigger the function (also WaitForSingleObject on the socket won't be triggered on a new connection).

Any idea?

Comment: you need use [AcceptEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737524(v=vs.85).aspx) instead `WSAAccept` - this api is asynchronous. you not need wait on it at all. if you bind you socket(second param) to IOCP - you got callback when connection finished

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [WSAWaitForMultipleEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742219(v=vs.85).aspx). For sockets, here's some pseudo code:

```
HANDLE hEvent[1];
hEvent[0] = WSACreateEvent();
WSAEventSelect(hSocket, hEvent[0], FD_READ | FD_WRITE);

while (WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(...)) {
    if (WSAEnumNetworkEvents(...)) { // Multiple events max exist
        if (... & FD_ACCEPT) {
        }
        if (... & FD_WRITE) {
        }
        ....
    }
}
```

If you use multiple events (e.g. a stop event to signal the thread to stop), use the return value from the WSAWaitForMultipleEvents to determine the signalled event (as you do with WaitForMultipleObjects).

Comment: This only lets you wait on WSA socket events, not standard Win32 event objects, so you would have to use a WSA socket event for the stop event, then you can wait on all of the events together with `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()`. If you want to use a standard event object for the stop event, then you have to use Overlapped I/O or IOCP for the socket operations (`AcceptEx()`, `WSARecv()`, `WSASend()`, etc) so you can assign standard event objects to each operation, and then you can use `WaitForMultipleObjects()`.

Comment: The events array for WSAWaitForMultipleEvents can handle multiple types ('The array can contain handles of objects of different types' is what the documentation says). The WSACreateEvent documentation adds: 'if a Windows application wants to use an auto-reset event rather than a manual-reset event, the application can call the CreateEvent function directly'.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot wait on socket handles directly.

`WSAAccept()` is synchronous, the only way to abort it is to close the listening socket.

For what you are attempting to do, use `AcceptEx()` instead, which is asynchronous and supports Overlapped I/O and I/O Completion Ports.

If you use Overlapped I/O, you can associate a standard Win32 event object to each Overlapped I/O capable socket operation (`AcceptEx()`, `WSARecv()`, `WSASend()`, etc), and use a standard Win32 event object for your stop event.  And then you can use a `WaitForMultipleObjects()` loop to know which event(s) are signaled and act accordingly.

If you use an I/O Completion Port, you don't need event objects at all.  You can associate each socket with a single IOCP queue, and your IOCP handler (either a call to `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` or a callback function) will be notified whenever each IOCP capable socket operation completes.  You can then use `PostQueuedCompletionStatus()` to post a custom stop message to the IOCP queue.  You IOCP handler can act accordingly based on what kind of event it receives.

Comment: `use PostQueuedCompletionStatus() to post a custom stop message to the IOCP queue` - we can bind socket to system handled queue by `BindIoCompletionCallback` or `CreateThreadpoolIo` - this queue not need to stop and have own handler. however if use self created IOCP - several working threads need create for handle this IOCP (usual number of threads == number of processors) - so need call `PostQueuedCompletionStatus` not once, but number of threads times - for notify every thread to stop.